# EAS application crash when it's launch

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I builded an application with the command `eas build -p android --profile preview`.
All the build work but when I tried to launch the application with my mobile phone, the application crash.
I tried to removed something to see where could be the problem and when I remove this code the application never crash:

```
import {createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/stack";
import {NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native";
import BottomTabNavigator from "./bottomBarNavigation";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function MyStack() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={BottomTabNavigator}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

BottomBarNavigation.js:

```
export default function BottomTabNavigator() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: styles.tabBar,
      }}
    >
      {TabArr.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <Tab.Screen
            key={index}
            name={item.route}
            component={item.component}
            options={{
              tabBarShowLabel: false,
              tabBarButton: (props) => <TabButton {...props} item={item} />,
            }}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I think the problem is when i used the navigation within the application but I'm not sure.
If someone could explain my problems and if you need more codes I can give you it.